# C - Temporary struct with memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, queue, malloc

This struct is supposed to have the infos for each item of a queue.

```
struct tx_queue_item_t {
    //user input
    uint8_t priority;      
    uint8_t attempts;    
    uint8_t *buff;
    size_t size;
    uint32_t timeout;               //10ms base
    //system input
    uint8_t idNum;
    uint8_t attemptCount;
    uint32_t tickCountAtTx;         //to check for receive timeout
    enum tx_queue_status_t status;
};
```

I would like to know if I'm able to have 'temporary items' (temporary structs), which free their own memory usage when such item of the queue be considered as done/processed.

Is there a way to make this in C? `malloc`?
Consider that I also want to access the values of variables by their names for each struct instance.
And also in order I can know what is the total memory being used for such purpose (create temporary items).

Regards.

Comment: The C language doesn't have any *built-in* "garbage collectors" ... so I guess the best way to go is to make custom functions to create and destroy your structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. C does not have widely-implemented garbage collectors. You can use an external library like [boehm-gc](https://www.hboehm.info/gc/), but that may not be what you want.

The most portable solution would be to use `malloc` and `free` manually, or use a function to create and destroy your structure.

Comment: Linked lists can be usefull for this case?

Comment: @abomin3v3l Yes, if you plan to use the function.